# Prestashop 1.6 - price saving issue.

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6, price

In my Ecommerce site made in Prestashop version 1.6, when I update price of an item from administrative panel , it randomly gets affected. Sometimes the price change saved does not get implemented. The site is live and had been working so far but found this issue recently.

Answer (score 7):

It's a bug of browsers:
[forge.prestashop.com](http://forge.prestashop.com/browse/PSCSX-8524)

This the post on the forum:
[PrestaShop forum](https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/563518-solved-problem-saving-products/#entry2429094)

This should be fix your problem:
[GitHub temporary fix](https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/blob/5566c2d9d7e4ab88a201b2c5cf10e1cda2ff7150/admin-dev/themes/default/template/controllers/products/helpers/form/form.tpl#L252-L254)

The final fix (merged in the main project): [GitHub full fix](https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/pull/6749/files)

**EDIT:** A temporary workaround that should works, when you save click exactly on the text "Save" or "Save and stay" and not on the button

Comment: The GitHub fix doesn't fix the problem - the change is already in the code

Comment: The change is from 1.6.1.9

Comment: Works from firefox. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Remove the following lines from the file /adminXXXX/themes/default/template/controllers/products/helpers/form/form.tpl: https://github.com/P...m.tpl#L252-L254

credit: https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/563518-solved-problem-saving-products/#entry2429094