# Back Office does not save product changes

Tags: php, mysql, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

Problem:
When I want to save changes in existing product and I click on **Save and Stay** sometimes page just refresh and changes are not saving, also there is no any information about error or success.

Some important informations:

- Prestashop version: 1.6.1.6
- PHP verion: 5.6.23
- Cache & Smarty: disabled and cleared
- Same effect on online server with proper file write permissions and locally with CHMODS all to 777

After I enabled `_PS_MODE_DEV_` and `_PS_DEBUG_PROFILING_` there are no errors but...

Each time I click on **Save and Stay** and operation finishes with succes (new changes are visible) I can see at the top of the page following information with link which I have to click to continue.

> Caught redirection to
>   index.php?controller=AdminLogin&token=291d9473550fa78075bdf305f5f03621&redirect=AdminProducts

When operation finishes with fail (changes are not visible) I don't see information about `caught redirection` and page just refreshes without my interraction.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40502348/prestashop-1-6-price-saving-issue) is most likely the problem.

Comment: Thank you, now I know what causes this bug. After search on stacoverflow I have not found question that you have posted. I updated Prestashop to the 1.6.1.9 version and for now I dont see any problems. Thank you for your help.